# Listener above all code in the application - connection

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following situation, I created an ErrorInterceptor which I added to Dio. In ErrorInterceptor, if an error occurs, I check:

```
  if (err.error is SocketException) {
    //Here we must implement logic for show message about offfline mode
  }
```

At this point, I would like to call code that displays a connection problem.

How can I do that a message is displayed with each request, regardless of where the request was called (LoginPage or another Nested View). I tried to add BlocListener at the very beginning of the application - unfortunately it doesn't work. I would not like to use a solution that is listening all the time.